How to create a new column in a dataset based on exact row values of 2 columns in another dataset in R?
I am trying to create a map of the United States with specific counties highlighted. I was trying to do this by using mutate() and case_when() to create a new column in the county map that indicates whether the county should be highlighted or not based off a list of counties derived from another dataset.
county.map <-map_data("county")

df <- data.frame(state=c("minnesota", "ohio", "west virginia"), county=c("olmsted", "lake", "kanawha"))

county.map.highlight <- county.map %>%
                mutate(highlight = case_when(region %in% df$state &
                                subregion %in% df$county ~"Yes",
                            TRUE ~ "No"))
ggplot(county.map.highlight) +
geom_polygon(county.map.highlight,
        mapping = aes(x= long,
                y=lat,
                group=group,
                fill=highlight),
        color="black")


The problem is that when I map county.map.highlight, counties that should not be highlighted, like Lake County, Minnesota, are highlighted.
How do I tell R to only change the highlight column to Yes when the rows in df are exact match (i.e., Lake County, Ohio will be highlighted but Lake County, Minnesota will not)?

Perhaps county.map.highlight <- county.map %>% right_join(df |> select(state,county))? That will take county.map and only keep the rows that can be linked to rows in df on those two key columns.

You can add the highlight indicator to the data frame that marks counties for inclusion, then join that data with county.map as suggested in Jon Spring's comment.
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

county.map <-map_data("county")

df <- data.frame(state=c("minnesota", "ohio", "west virginia"),
                 county=c("olmsted", "lake", "kanawha"),
                 highlight = 'Yes')

county.map |>
  left_join(df, by = join_by(region == state, subregion == county)) |>
  mutate(highlight = tidyr::replace_na(highlight, 'No')) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = highlight)) +
  geom_polygon(color = 'black') +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')



Perfect! Thank you!
